# Synergy's menus go dark about 20 seconds after launching the application

Tags: 11.10, menu, synergy

Synergy's menus go dark about 20 seconds after launching the application *(Synergy is an awesome CAD tool if you were wondering).* I used to be able to solve this by turning off "decorations" in the "appearance" settings under gnome-based versions of ubuntu.  I've been fiddling with the compiz settings to try to find similar settings to work around this, but so far I've had no luck.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Any fixes?

Also, does anyone know of a place where I can read what the greying-out or darkening of menus means?  Its a very effective form of user feedback, in that it really conveys the sense that something is wrong with the running program.  But its also kind of shallow, in that it gives the user no detail about the underlying problem.  If a menu goes dark to indicate a problem, is there a log file or something that might provide more detailed clues?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Ah the joys of forced 3d support.  You can still boot into gnome-fallback mode.  That should disable 3D window decorations for you...before you log in check the other session options.